# Use coalesce in a subquery while creating a view

Tags: subquery, concatenation, coalesce, isnull

I am currently trying to make a view in order to show the name of the clients that have purchased a car (new or used) and need to show "NA" when the client name is NULL.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('V_PrixSuperieurMoyenne','V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW V_PrixSuperieurMoyenne;
GO

CREATE VIEW V_PrixSuperieurMoyenne
AS
(
    SELECT
        CS.[State],
        CI.ListPrice,
        CI.CarInventoryID,
        COALESCE(CONCAT(C.Name, ' ', C.FirstName), 'NA') AS 'Nom du Client',
        (
            SELECT AVG(CI.ListPrice)
            FROM CarInventory CI
            INNER JOIN CarState CS ON CS.CarStateID = CI.CarStateID
            WHERE CS.State = 'New'
        ) AS 'Prix Moyen Neuf'
    FROM
        CarInventory CI
        INNER JOIN CarState CS ON CS.CarStateID = CI.CarStateID
        LEFT JOIN Invoice I ON I.CarInventoryID = CI.CarInventoryID
        LEFT JOIN Client C ON C.ClientID = I.ClientID
    GROUP BY
        CS.State,
        CI.ListPrice,
        CI.CarInventoryID,
        CONCAT(C.Name , ' ', C.FirstName)
)
GO

SELECT *
FROM V_PrixSuperieurMoyenne
ORDER BY 1,2
GO
```

Here is my code, however it seems like the COALESCE doesn't work as when I try to run the code, when the names are NULL, it only shows an empty string. I need it to show 'NA'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function will return ' ' when `C.Name` and `C.FirstName` are NULL. However, if you replace `CONCAT` with string additions, you will get `NULL` as you expect, because a single `NULL` value in a line of string additions nulls out the entire string.

```
-- Returns 'NA' when C.Name or C.FirstName are NULL.    
COALESCE(C.Name + ' ' + C.FirstName,'NA')
```

You could also replace `COALESCE` with `ISNULL` since you're only checking nullity of a single item:

```
ISNULL(C.Name +' ' + C.FirstName,'NA')
```

Be sure to make this change in your `GROUP BY`, too.

`COALESCE` is typically used when you want to check whether multiple items are `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you, the string addition was something I didn't think about.